# How to create a Ruby executable using ocra or rubyscript2exe gems but including needed Excel files?

Tags: ruby, excel, executable, ocra

I have a dozen of selenium webdriver scripts written in Ruby and I have used both rubyscript2exe and ocra gems in an attempt to end up with a 'bundled' executable but to no avail. Problem is, my scripts are grabbing test data from Excel files; and this is causing havoc when trying to create the executable.

It works fine on the machine which has the original excel file but when taken home away from its native path it 'll just refuse to run. Do I need to declare my paths in my code in a relative way and not explicitly? Is there a command in Ruby like 'require' but for an Excel file for example?

I will be grateful if anyone knows a way to make a ruby executable (or even an installer/application builder) which will somehow include the Excel files running in parallel with the script.

*** Resolved ***

Admins you can close this one if you want.

It was pretty simple but couldn't figure it out on the first place. If you want to included additional non ruby files in your final executable you can use the line below..:

ocra yourscript.rb test.xls docs\documentantion.doc excel\additional.xls

Answer (score 0):

Once you package an exe using Ocra the files are locked inside it, and if they're intended to be immutable you may as well store the data in the script and write it out directly from there. If you absolutely can't do it without an excel file you'd might also consider creating one via the script. 
If you're using an external excel file which is distributed with the exe, then you'd be best off referencing the excel file's path relative to the script (Dir.pwd). Also, wouldn't it be more efficient to gather the data from a delimited text file rather than excel?

Comment: First of all thank you for your feedback..Maybe me I didn't explain myself very well, there is one more guy here at SO who has the same problem like me..My script already creates AND uses an external excel file..The problem is when I am packaging everything with ocra it will work only in my machine where the excel file needs to be present, when taken to other PC it gives you an error..In other words the problem that I've got is that the absolutely essential excel file is NOT BUNDLED inside the exe..Good idea the txt file but the same problem will remain as I suspect..